# DropDownList has a strange behavior

Tags: asp.net, controls

The aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlTimeZone" DataSource ="<%# TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().ToDictionary(z => z.DisplayName)%>" DataTextField="Key" DataValueField="Value">`
```

The html:

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlTimeZone" id="MainContent_ddlTimeZone">
<option value="(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West">(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West</option>
<option value="(UTC-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa">(UTC-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
<option value="(UTC-10:00) Hawaii">(UTC-10:00) Hawaii</option>
<option value="(UTC-09:00) Alaska">(UTC-09:00) Alaska</option>
<option value="(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)">(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>
<option value="(UTC-08:00) Tijuana, Baja California">(UTC-08:00) Tijuana, Baja California</option>
<option value="(UTC-07:00) Arizona">(UTC-07:00) Arizona</option>
<option value="(UTC-07:00) Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan">(UTC-07:00) Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan</option>
```

When I try to get the **ddlTimeZone.SelectedValue** I always get null (or -1, I don't remember) and the **SelectedItem** always equals null.

Comment: More code. Databinding, when? Are you trying to access the value before the control data been reloaded after a postback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've understoond. It is all along of

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
            DataBind();
    }
```